# Maven dependency error in bonigarcia and redis.clients

Tags: maven, pom.xml, mvn-repo

In my pom.xml file out of all dependencies these 2 dependencies are giving error

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
        <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
    <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I have tried changing the versions, adding  for these dependencies and mvn clean install. But still not able to resolve this dependency error.

My maven version is 3.6.3 and Java version is 16.0.1

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/947Vc.png)

Comment: What exactly is the error? Show the output... BTW: Why using an old version of Maven and why using an old Version of the JDK ?

Comment: Lookds like that dependencies are not in maven central repository, so you have to speciify additional repositories for maven to search dependencies (if they are in one maven repo). https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html

Comment: I am getting dependency error in IntelliJ for these two dependencies. I have downloaded them from mvn central repository https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/redis.clients/jedis

Comment: @AravindM. please add a snapshot of the error. Otherwise, the best guess is that IntelliJ IDEA indexes are not up-to-date so try updating them. You can check the documentation on common IntelliJ IDEA / Maven issues troubleshooting https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/troubleshooting-common-maven-issues.html#maven_start_problem

Comment: @tmarwen I have added error screenshot. I will go through the troubleshooting link that you shared and check if it is getting resolved

Comment: Issue is resolved. It was due to duplication of dependencies in pom.xml.